# Python Replace method producing wrong values

Tags: python

I am trying to solve the following `Caesar Cipher` problem on Hacker Rank but i am stuck. The function is producing wrong output for some test cases as shown

```
def caesarCipher(s,k):
    
    alph = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    len_alph = len(alph)
    
    new_chars={}
    
    for char in alph:
        new_index = alph.index(char) + k
        if  new_index < len_alph:
            new_char = alph[new_index]
            new_chars[char]=new_char
        else:
            new_char = alph[new_index-len_alph]
            new_chars[char]=new_char
            
    for char in s:
        if char.lower() in alph:
            dict_char = new_chars[char.lower()]
            dict_char = dict_char.lower() if char.islower() else dict_char.upper()
#             print(dict_char)
            s = s.replace(char, dict_char)
      
             
    return s
```

When i do `print` i can see that i am able to capture correct substrings from my dictionary. Yet the replace function is producing different values. Could anyone help me figure out where is the issue with this code. Thank you very much

Comment: hint what is `"hello".replace("l", "e").replace("e", "x")`?

Comment: hint see [str.translate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate).

Comment: How does it fail?  Provide inputs and expected vs. actual outputs and full tracebacks of errors, if any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Miguel Sánchez. I did the modifications as below and the function is working.

```
def caesarCipher(s,k):
    
    alph = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    len_alph = len(alph)
    new_s =[]
    
    
    new_chars={}
    
    for char in alph:
        new_index = 0
        new_index = alph.index(char) + k
        if  new_index < len_alph:
            new_char = alph[new_index]
            new_chars[char]=new_char
        else:
            while new_index >= len_alph:
                new_index -= len_alph
            new_char = alph[new_index]
            new_chars[char]=new_char
            
    for char in s:
        if char.lower() in alph:
            dict_char = new_chars[char.lower()]
            dict_char = dict_char.lower() if char.islower() else dict_char.upper()
            new_s.append(dict_char)
        else:
            new_s.append(char)
      
             
    return ''.join(new_s)
```

Answer (score 4):

Seems that the problem is on the line

```
s = s.replace(char, dict_char)
```

Even though this line is at first sight correct, the replace function is operating over the whole string and therefore it changes the values that have been already cyphered. Another method should be considered as appending the cyphered values onto a list or something similar.

An example of this case is calling the function `caesarCipher("abc", 1)` the expected output is `bcd`, but when calling the function the last foreach would execute and replace all character "a" by "b" so that your string results on `bbc`. Then it would do it again by replacing "b" by "c" so that it would be `ccc`, and once more (from "c" to "d") would end up being `ddd`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly the question is, but it seems you are understanding what caser cipher is in a wrong way. Rotation in caesar cipher does not mean shifting characters in a clockwise direction ( which you seem to be doing) but instead increasing the character by k.
what I mean by that if k = 3
'a' becomes 'd'
as a corresponds to 1(first alphabet) and 1 + 3 = 4 which corresponds to d.
Now you might think that it is giving the right answer for some test cases.
That is because for a string like 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' the answer is 'defghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabc' which is the same if you rotate the strings by shifting characters and rotating the string according to Caesar Cipher i.e by adding.

Comment: Have a look at my response above. You can try to run it on your machine. the function is working as specified  here https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/caesar-cipher-1/problem?utm_campaign=challenge-recommendation&utm_medium=email&utm_source=24-hour-campaign

Answer (score 0):

As a previous poster suggested, make a list of the new characters and then, completing that thought, make a string, say str_1 = '', and then use str_1.join(list) to convert the new characters into a string.

Comment: This version of the code you posted gets the job done, for sentences of words with spaces between them.

Comment: Read my answer to the question..thats what i have done